# jQuery datatables don't show table if haven't data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jquery datatables with server side fetch data, my problem is when table of data is empty datatables hide table and don't show that, i want to show table with no any data on table message, how to have this option?

```
oTable_topics =$('#showTopics').dataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 12,                               
    "bScrollCollapse": true,       
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php",
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true,
    // "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
     // $('td:eq(5)', nRow).html("<ul class='styledlist' style='width:80px !important;'><img src='http://localhost/shirazee/UI/images/icons/publish.png' style='border:none;'/></ul>");
    // },
    "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
        clickRowHandler_topics();
        if ( oSettings.aiDisplay.length == 0 )
        {
            return;
        }                       
        var nTrs = $('tbody tr', oSettings.nTable);
        var iColspan = nTrs[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length;
        var sLastGroup = "";
        for ( var i=0 ; i<nTrs.length ; i++ )
        {
            var iDisplayIndex = oSettings._iDisplayStart + i;
            var sGroup = oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[iDisplayIndex] ]._aData[0];
            if ( sGroup != sLastGroup )
            {
                var nGroup = document.createElement( 'tr' );
                var nCell = document.createElement( 'td' );
                nCell.colSpan = iColspan;
                nCell.className = "group";
                nCell.innerHTML = sGroup;
                nGroup.appendChild( nCell );
                nTrs[i].parentNode.insertBefore( nGroup, nTrs[i] );
                sLastGroup = sGroup;
            }
        }
    },
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
    ],
    "aaSortingFixed": [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
      aoData.push(
         {"name": "id"   ,      "value": "i.id" },          
         {"name": "subject"   , "value": "i.subject" },
         {"name": "date_time",  "value": "i.date_time"} ,
         {"name": "posted_by",  "value": "u.username"} ,
         {"name": "ctitle"   ,  "value": "c.title"} ,
         {"name": "etitle"   ,  "value": "e.title"},
         {"name": "istatus"   ,  "value": "i.status"},
         {"name": "join"     ,  "value": "JOIN categories c ON i.category = c.id JOIN status_topics e ON i.status = e.id JOIN users u ON i.posted_by = c.id"},
         {"name": "action"   ,  "value": "topics" }
      )}
    });
    function clickRowHandler_topics() {
        $('#showTopics tbody tr').bind('click', function () {
            var aData = oTable_topics.fnGetData( this );
            iId_topics = aData[1];
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

To toggle the table visibility depending on the number of result, simply use the property `fnDrawCallback`:

```
var _grid = $("#myTable").dataTable({
    fnDrawCallback: function (settings) {
        $("#myTable").parent().toggle(settings.fnRecordsDisplay() > 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: hiiii  i am use this code but if table have data then also not display table and   i am use class not id  for table becouse no of table create dynamic any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as

```
$('#showTopics').dataTable( {
    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable" : "Your custom message for empty table"
    }
} );
```

Just add this

```
"oLanguage": {
    "sEmptyTable" : "Your custom message for empty table"
}
```

Comment: thanks, but my table is hide now, that does not any data on table to show it.

Comment: This is for an empty table, you can show your message when there is no data.

Comment: yes Sheikh Heera my problem is this. table is hide and i cant show it. i', using server side property

Comment: I'm confused! You use server side property, what does that mean ? Is your table is hidden from the server using `display:none` property when there is no data ?

Comment: yes property dont have any data, i'm, using join on mysql command and when that could not find any data hide the table, that means is i dont use datatable for fill table directly, i'm using ajax

Comment: How you hide it ? Now, if you want to show it then don't hide it.

Comment: Or if it's hidden and you want to show on the client side then you can use `$('#showTopics').show().dataTable({ ... })`

Comment: Or if you need to add an empty row then you can add a row like `$('#showTopics').show().dataTable().fnAddData( ['&nbsp;', '&nbsp;'] )`, add as many `&nbsp;` as many columns you have.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is if your table is empty of all data don't show any datatable. That's not something you can do in your table init directly.

What you'd need to do is test the output coming from your "sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php" and see if it's empty:

```
$.getJSON( "server_processing.php", function( data ) {
    if( this = "" || NULL ) {
        // add css hidden classes to all datatables elements
        $("#showTopics").addClass("hidden");
        $(".your-th-and-thead-classes").addClass("hidden");
    }
}
```

Then in your CSS can just do:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DataTables provides a callback that's triggered when the table loads (e.g. when the server-side call completes.) You can put arbitrary code there to modify the table however you like.

For example, to hide your table on load:

```
var myTable = $("#my_table");
myTable.dataTable({

    "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
        myTable.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myTable = $("#my_table");
myTable.dataTable({
        "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings) {
           if (oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.length <= 0) {
               $("#my_table_wrapper").hide();
           }
        }
});
```

Edit(add description): based on [event doc](https://datatables.net/reference/event/init) and [setting doc](https://datatables.net/reference/api/settings()) we see that the DisplayMaster contain the number of elements in the table and based on HTML render, the table have a global div with class = "table class"+ _wrapper"  with default settings. so if we don't have elements we hide this  div.

maybe this is not the best solution but it's work.

Comment: i add explanation, but @TobySpeight https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114776 ("Then again; often a short snippet of code really is all that is needed. I've seen some answers that went on and on and on with explanations of stuff that doesn't so much matter...") . like this question.